# How sort an arraylist of names in alphabetical order but names which start with numbers must comes last

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

i need to sort names list  in to alphabetical order, for this i use the interfase comperator for sorting the names

```
  @Override
    public int compareTo(ContactModel another) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getname().compareTo(another.getname());
    }
```

Suppose this is my array of name

```
123vinish
23Sathya
24mahesh
Ranjith
Vipin
Bibin
Shine
Thomas
```

i need to sort this in a sequence where names with numbers must come last

```
Bibin
Ranjith
Shine
Thomas
Vipin
123Vinish
23Sathya
24mahesh
```

How can we implement this

Answer (score 8):

`String.compareTo(String)` sort the Strings by the ascii value of the characters. You need to change the comparator. Example with a custom comparator:

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add("123vinish");
al.add("23Sathya");
al.add("24mahesh");
al.add("Ranjith");
al.add("Vipin");
al.add("Bibin");
al.add("Shine");
al.add("Thomas");

Comparator<String> nameComparator  = new Comparator<String>() 
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String value1, String value2)
    {
        if(Character.isDigit(value1.charAt(0))&&!Character.isDigit(value2.charAt(0)))
            return 1;
        if(Character.isDigit(value2.charAt(0))&&!Character.isDigit(value1.charAt(0)))
            return -1;
        return value1.compareTo(value2);
    }
};

Collections.sort(al, nameComparator);

System.out.println(al);
```

**Output:** `[Bibin, Ranjith, Shine, Thomas, Vipin, 123vinish, 23Sathya, 24mahesh]`

And if you want to override the `compareTo` method in the class where you implemented the `Comparable<>` interface, it have to look like this:

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ContactModel anotherValue)
    {
        if(Character.isDigit(this.getname().charAt(0))&&!Character.isDigit(anotherValue.getname().charAt(0)))
            return 1;
        if(Character.isDigit(anotherValue.getname().charAt(0))&&!Character.isDigit(this.getname().charAt(0)))
            return -1;
        return this.getname().compareTo(anotherValue.getname());
    }
```

**EDIT:** 
If you want that a String like `2a` appear before something like `23` then you only have to loop over every character in the String. Then the custom comparator have to look like this:

```
Comparator<String> nameComparator  = new Comparator<String>() 
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String value1, String value2)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(value1.length(), value2.length()); i++)
        {
            //value1 is digit and value2 is not
            if(Character.isDigit(value1.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(value2.charAt(i)))
                return 1;
            //value2 is digit and value1 is not
            else if(Character.isDigit(value2.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(value1.charAt(i)))
                return -1;
            //both are digits with different size
            else if(Character.isDigit(value1.charAt(i)) && Character.isDigit(value2.charAt(i)) && Integer.valueOf(value1.charAt(i))!=Integer.valueOf(value2.charAt(i)))
                return value1.compareTo(value2);
            //both are no digits
            else if(!Character.isDigit(value1.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(value2.charAt(i)))   
                return value1.compareTo(value2);
            //loop again if they are both digits with the same value
        }
        return value1.compareTo(value2);
    }
};
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have creat another solution for your problem. I've copied the implementation of the `compareTo`  method in String class and modified the ascii values of numbers while the comparing. This example can be used in your `ContactModel` class.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(ContactModel anotherValue) {
    int len1 = this.getname().length();
    int len2 = anotherValue.getname().length();
    int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
    char v1[] = this.getname().toCharArray();
    char v2[] = anotherValue.getname().toCharArray();

    int k = 0;
    while (k < lim) {
        //Do the trick here! If char is a digit, add 75.
        char c1 = Character.isDigit(v1[k]) ? ((char)(v1[k]+75)) : v1[k];  
        char c2 = Character.isDigit(v2[k]) ? ((char)(v2[k]+75)) : v2[k];
        if (c1 != c2) {
            return c1 - c2;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return len1 - len2;
}
```

Comment: How about "2a" and "23"?

Comment: From the example given, 23 should come before 2a and this solution correctly handles that scenario.

Comment: @miniBill I implemented another solution. In this solution 2a will appear befor 23.

Comment: @miniBill i cant use XOR to merge the first two if statements into one, because i have to return 1 or -1. I can merge the last two if statements into one, but i didnt because of the higher readability.

Comment: I have implemented another solution, this will exactly work like `String.compareTo(String)`, but numbers will be appear after letters.

Answer (score 0):

What about this implementation almost similar to your 2nd suggestion

```
@Override
public int compareTo(ContactModel another) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean lhsStartsWithDigit = Character.isDigit(getStartLetter().charAt(0));
    boolean rhsStartsWithDigit= Character.isDigit(another.getStartLetter().charAt(0));
    if((lhsStartsWithDigit && rhsStartsWithDigit) || (!lhsStartsWithDigit && ! rhsStartsWithDigit))
        return getStartLetter().compareToIgnoreCase(another.getStartLetter());
    else if(lhsStartsWithDigit)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;

}
```

Can i follow this??